# Salesforce UnitTest exception message: "You cannot make callout after creating a Savepoint" test error

Tags: unit-test, callout, savepoint

I have noticed very strange behavior while executing test.

In one method on the class i test Savepoint is created. This method is used also in test for creation of records. After that there is a startTest statement so it should run ok.

But for some reason i get:You cannot make callout after creating a Savepoint exception thrown. I tried googling but there is not a single result that would even appear.

What makes it even weirder is that the the similar setup works in another test case.

Has anyone ecountered this?

Comment: Hello, zokito, have you checked the test execution log to confirm whether the test method _is_ or _isn't_ attempting to make a callout, after creating a `Savepoint`?

Comment: hi Marty, the issue lies in the following (i think) i have the following setup - static manager class that does all the operations on records of certain type in one create operation, since there are a lot of consecutive dml calls i have Savepoint set (savepoint is method scoped). This part is all done before start test is called (i think this should do all the commits etc so the context should be clear). I then do the callout on the same static class and i get this exception. The weird thing is if i do a callout directly from test not from the manager class (all is static) it goes well.

Comment: And answer to your question is it does but after test.StartTest

Comment: Hello, zokito, is there any way you can post some of your code? I tried to reproduce the error you got, but I got a very different error message: _Methods defined as TestMethod do not support Web service callouts, test skipped_

Comment: Hi Marty i can't really post the code since i have an nda but i can make a stripped down version of the setup but i currently don't have proper time to do it. And for your situation you should use the HttpCalloutMock interface as described here http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_httpcalloutmock.htm

Comment: Hello, zokito, thank you for the reminder about `HttpCalloutMock`. I've implemented this, and I'm able to reproduce the same error you described. However, I get the _same error_ regardless of whether I make the callout using a static method or whether I do it directly in the test method. This makes me think the behavior is expected and something to consider when designing solutions. Here are the classes I'm using in the simple setup: http://pastebin.com/6X9XN0Bn and http://pastebin.com/FkSEcKAE

Comment: Hi @MartyC. sorry for the long period of silence, but i'm just in over my head. I've made a workaround for this situation: `if(!Tesst.isRunningTest()){create savepoint}` does the trick. thanks for your effort really appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If anyone ends up in the same situation the way to solve this is:
`if(!Test.isRunningTest())
{
   create savepoint
}`

be careful not to forget to use the same
`if(!Test.isRunningTest())
{
   restore savepoint
}`

if you're restoring.

Comment: one _s_ to many in _Test_